# SQL - Period range in subgroups of a group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, analytics

I have the following dataset:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2018-08-14 |
| 1 | John | 2018-08-20 |
| 1 | John | 2018-09-03 |
| 2 | John | 2018-11-13 |
| 2 | John | 2018-12-11 |
| 2 | John | 2018-12-12 |
| 1 | John | 2020-01-20 |
| 1 | John | 2020-01-21 |
| 3 | John | 2021-03-02 |
| 3 | John | 2021-03-03 |
| 1 | John | 2020-05-10 |
| 1 | John | 2020-05-12 |

And I would like to have the following result:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2018-08-14 |
| 2 | John | 2018-11-13 |
| 1 | John | 2020-01-20 |
| 3 | John | 2021-03-02 |
| 1 | John | 2020-05-10 |

If I group by A, B the 1st row and the third just concatenate which is coherent. How could I create another columns to still use a group by and have the result I want. 
If you have another ideas than mine, please explain it !

I tried to use some first, last, rank, dense_rank without success.

Comment: What is the rule to return the combination of (1, John) twice for the same year?

Comment: The order of the dataset was important. That's why we can't group by A and B. This is why I was stuck : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lag(). Looks like B is a function of A in your data. So checking lag(A) will suffice.

```
select A,B,C
from (
    select *, case when lag(A) over(order by C) = A then 0 else 1 end startFlag
    from mytable 
) t
where startFlag = 1
order by C
```